# How to control the order of yield in Scrapy

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

Help! Reading the following scrapy code and the result of crawler. I want to crawl some data from http://china.fathom.info/data/data.json, and only **Scrapy** is allowed. But I don't know how to control the order of yield. I look forward to process all **parse_member** request in the loop and then return the **group_item**, but seems yield item is always executed before yield request.

```
start_urls = [
    "http://china.fathom.info/data/data.json"
]

def parse(self, response):
    groups = json.loads(response.body)['group_members']
    for i in groups:
        group_item = GroupItem()
        group_item['name'] = groups[i]['name']
        group_item['chinese'] = groups[i]['chinese']
        group_item['members'] = []

        members = groups[i]['members']
        for member in members:
            yield Request(self.person_url % member['id'], meta={'group_item': group_item, 'member': member},
                          callback=self.parse_member, priority=100)
        yield group_item

def parse_member(self, response):
    group_item = response.meta['group_item']
    member = response.meta['member']
    person = json.loads(response.body)
    ego = person['ego']
    group_item['members'].append({
        'id': ego['id'],
        'name': ego['name'],
        'chinese': ego['chinese'],
        'role': member['role']
    })
```

[Data on MongoDB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woLIT.jpg)

Comment: maybe move `yield group_item` from `parse()` to `parse_member()`

Comment: what do you mean by "seems yield item is always executed before yield request."? maybe are you seeing that the **response** for this Request is received after you see the item printed to the console? In that case it's expected

Comment: @furas I had tried to move `yield group _item` to parse_member(), but the result is `{'A':1, 'members':[{'id':11}]}, {'A':1, 'members':[{'id':22}]}` instead of `{'A':1, 'members':[{'id':11}, {'id':22}]}`, I didn't know how  to resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to yield the item on the final callback, `parse` isn't stopping for `parse_member` to finish, so the `group_item` in `parse` isn't changing while `parse_member` is working.

Don't yield the `group_item` of `parse`, just the one on `parse_member`, as you already copied the previous item on `meta` and you already recovered it on `parse_member` with `response.meta['group_item']`

Comment: Do you mean that I need to yield the item on `parse_member`?

Comment: Yes that's what I meant

Comment: As I commented to **@furas**, this cannot return members `list`. do you have any idea?

Comment: please check your code, or update it, I only see you append one element to `group_item['members']`

Comment: there is `for member in members:` in `parse`.

Comment: you are not appending those objects to `group_item['members']`, and this isn't scrapy related, but a python problem, please correct your code, debug it and try to fix it.