# How to yield several requests in order in Scrapy?

Tags: scrapy, python-requests, yield

I need to send my requests **in order** with Scrapy.

```
def n1(self, response) :
    #self.input = [elem1,elem2,elem3,elem4,elem5, .... ,elem100000]
    for (elem,) in self.input :

        link =  urljoin(path,elem)

        yield Request(link)
```

My problem is that the requests are not in the order. 
I read [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33875339/how-to-control-the-order-of-yield-in-scrapy) but it has no correct answer.

How should I change my code for sending the requests in order?

**UPDATE 1**

I used priority and changed my code to

```
def n1(self, response) :

    #self.input = [elem1,elem2,elem3,elem4,elem5, .... ,elem100000]
    self.prio = len(self.input)
    for (elem,) in self.input :
        self.prio -= 1
        link =  urljoin(path,elem)

        yield Request(link, priority=self.prio)
```

And my setting for this spider is

```
custom_settings = {
    'DOWNLOAD_DELAY' : 0,
    'COOKIES_ENABLED' : True,
    'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS' : 1 ,
    'AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED' : False,
}
```

Now the order is changed, but it's not in the order of elements in the array

Comment: Try to check `priority` in Request: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html

Comment: @ElenaSh. Thanks, I tried your suggestion, and updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `return` statement instead of `yield`.

You don't even need to touch any setting:

```
from scrapy.spiders import Spider, Request

class MySpider(Spider):

    name = 'toscrape.com'
    start_urls = ['http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-1.html']

    urls = (
        'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-{}.html'.format(i + 1) for i in range(50)
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        for url in self.urls:
            return Request(url)
```

Output:

```
2018-11-20 03:35:43 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-1.html> (referer: http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-1.html)
2018-11-20 03:35:43 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-2.html> (referer: http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-1.html)
2018-11-20 03:35:44 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-3.html> (referer: http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-2.html)
2018-11-20 03:35:44 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-4.html> (referer: http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-3.html)
2018-11-20 03:35:45 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-5.html> (referer: http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-4.html)
2018-11-20 03:35:45 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-6.html> (referer: http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-5.html)
2018-11-20 03:35:45 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-7.html> (referer: http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-6.html)
2018-11-20 03:35:46 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-8.html> (referer: http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-7.html)
2018-11-20 03:35:46 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-9.html> (referer: http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-8.html)
2018-11-20 03:35:47 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-10.html> (referer: http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-9.html)
2018-11-20 03:35:47 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-11.html> (referer: http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-10.html)
2018-11-20 03:35:47 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-12.html> (referer: http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-11.html)
2018-11-20 03:35:48 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-13.html> (referer: http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-12.html)
2018-11-20 03:35:48 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-14.html> (referer: http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-13.html)
2018-11-20 03:35:49 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-15.html> (referer: http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-14.html)
2018-11-20 03:35:49 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-16.html> (referer: http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-15.html)
2018-11-20 03:35:50 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-17.html> (referer: http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-16.html)
2018-11-20 03:35:50 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-18.html> (referer: http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-17.html)
2018-11-20 03:35:50 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-19.html> (referer: http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-18.html)
2018-11-20 03:35:51 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-20.html> (referer: http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-19.html)
2018-11-20 03:35:51 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-21.html> (referer: http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-20.html)
2018-11-20 03:35:52 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-22.html> (referer: http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-21.html)
2018-11-20 03:35:52 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-23.html> (referer: http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-22.html)
2018-11-20 03:35:53 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-24.html> (referer: http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-23.html)
2018-11-20 03:35:53 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-25.html> (referer: http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-24.html)
```

With a `yield` statement, the engine gets all the responses from the generator and executes them in an arbitrary order (I suspect they might be stored in some sort of set to remove duplicates).

Answer (score 0):

I think concurrent request is play at here. You can try setting

```
custom_settings = {
    'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 1
}
```

Default setting is 8. It will kind of explain why priority will not honoured when you have other workers free for work.

Comment: I have         'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS' : 1 ,'AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED' : False, in my settings

Answer (score 0):

You can send the next request only after receiving the previous one:

```
class MainSpider(Spider):
    urls = [
        'https://www.url1...',
        'https://www.url2...',
        'https://www.url3...',
    ]

    def start_requests(self):
        yield Request(
            url=self.urls[0],
            callback=self.parse,
            meta={'next_index': 1},
        )

    def parse(self, response):
        next_index = response.meta['next_index']

        # do something with response...

        # Process next url
        if next_index < len(self.urls):
            yield Request(
                url=self.urls[next_index],
                callback=self.parse,
                meta={'next_index': next_index+1},
            )
```